# In C#, what is the best way to parse out this value from a string?

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I have to parse out the system name  from a larger string.  The system name has a prefix of "ABC" and then a number.  Some examples are:

```
ABC500
ABC1100
ABC1300
```

the full string where i need to parse out the system name from can look like any of the items below:

```
ABC1100 - 2ppl
ABC1300
ABC 1300
ABC-1300
Managers Associates Only (ABC1100 - 2ppl)
```

before I saw the last one, i had this code that worked pretty well:

```
string[] trimmedStrings = jobTitle.Split(new char[] { '-', '–' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                           .Select(s => s.Trim())
                           .ToArray();

return trimmedStrings[0];
```

but it fails on the last example where there is a bunch of other text before the ABC.

Can anyone suggest a more elegant and future proof way of parsing out the system name here?

Comment: IMHO, Regex is the right way. you should form a regex that matches characters suffixed by numerics

Comment: The RegEx `(?<=ABC)[0-9]+` should get you straight to the numeric part.

Comment: You might want to check out [A sscanf() Replacement for .NET](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-sscanf-replacement-for-net).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this:

```
string[] strings =
{
    "ABC1100 - 2ppl",
    "ABC1300",
    "ABC 1300",
    "ABC-1300",
    "Managers Associates Only (ABC1100 - 2ppl)"
};

var reg = new Regex(@"ABC[\s,-]?[0-9]+");

var systemNames = strings.Select(line => reg.Match(line).Value);

systemNames.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

prints:

```
ABC1100
ABC1300
ABC 1300
ABC-1300
ABC1100
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/U6dTQ5)

Comment: What does the `*` do? As opposed to the `+` used in Shaamaan's answer.

Comment: Plus, I don't think they ask anywhere in the question for just the numeric part.

Comment: `*` indicates any amount of decimals (including no decimals at all). `+` indicates one or more is required.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko thanks for note. I really think whether `*` or `+` is required solely depends on the domain. Is `ABC` should be extracted or not?..

Comment: @IlyaIvanov, I wasn't questioning your usage of `*`, I don't do Regex's so was asking so I could understand it better.

Comment: @Ilya - thanks for the response.  I just updated the question as i found one example where there is a space inbetween the ABC and the number..  Any suggestion to make sure those are included?

Comment: @Ilya - thanks for the response. I just updated the question as i found one example where there is a space inbetween the ABC and the number.. I could just do this before the parse: name = name.Replace("ABC ", "ABC");

Comment: @leora updated my answer to parse `ABC 1300`. Are there any remaining issues?

Comment: @Ilya - thanks for the update.  Apologize but I found one other exception where there is a "-" in between the ABC and the 1300 :(.  Again i can "preprocess" that with a name = name.Replace("ABC-", "ABC"); if it makes it simpler . .

Comment: @leora it's ok, I can make in any non-alphabetic symbol between ABC and number, should I? Or Should I just add space or `-`? Updated my answer with `-`

Answer (score 2):

You really could leverage a Regex and get better results. This one should do the trick `[A-Za-z]{3}\d+`, and here is a [Rubular to prove it](http://rubular.com/r/otbxkY2IyT). Then in the code use it like this:

```
var matches = Regex.Match(someInputString, @"[A-Za-z]{3}\d+");
if (matches.Success) {
    var val = matches.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to parse this. There may be better expressions, but this one works for your case:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string txt="ABC500";

      string re1="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))";   
      string re2="(\\d+)"

      Regex r = new Regex(re1+re2,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
      Match m = r.Match(txt);
      if (m.Success)
      {
            String word1=m.Groups[1].ToString();
            String int1=m.Groups[2].ToString();
            Console.Write("("+word1.ToString()+")"+"("+int1.ToString()+")"+"\n");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use `Regex` for this. Depending on the exact nature of the system name, something like this could prove to be enough:

`Regex systemNameRegex = new Regex(@"ABC[0-9]+");`

If the *ABC* part of the name can change, you can modify the `Regex` to something like this:

`Regex systemNameRegex = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+");`